# How to get counts of each value in a column?

Tags: r, bigdata, plyr

I have a large dataset with many more columns than this but I'll simplify it for the purposes of this question.

Ethnicity | QuestionID | ResponseID

I would like to use R to find the Answer counts for a specific question for a specific ethnicity. Ie, Ethnicity=="Asian", QuestionID==10, ResponseID==2

How would I go about doing this?

I've tried using the plyr library with the following code:

```
library(plyr)

visData <- read.csv(file="/Users/gtye/Documents/Big Data/Medicare_claims___Vision_and_Eye_Health_Surveillance.csv"), header=TRUE, sep=",")

count(visData, c("RaceEthnicityID", "QuestionID", "ResponseID"))
```

But all I get is this, which is not exactly what I want.

[image]

Before you flame me, I've looked all over for hours and I just am too much of a noob to know what to even search for. Pls help :(

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

visData <- visData %>%
  group_by(raceEthnicityID, QuestionID, ResponseID) %>%
  summarize(response_count = n())
```

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for the kind response James. I tried learning R about 3 years ago and gave up because I kept getting flamed whenever I asked questions on here.

Comment: Second of all, I entered what you wrote and got this as a result: `Error: Column \`ResponseID\` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 1622`

Comment: I tried this and didn't get any output, see here: https://i.imgur.com/7XAwiH3.png

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me towards tidyverse, though, looks like it's a very useful package!

Comment: You don't get output because it's assigned to a new object. remove  `visData <-`  if you just want it printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you and should run without any Error

```
require(dplyr) ## Same as library

visData_subset <- visData %>% 
                    group_by(raceEthnicityID, QuestionID, ResponseID) %>% 
                    filter(raceEthnicityID=="Asian", QuestionID==10, 
                           ResponseID == 2) %>% 
                    summarize(response_count = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i take "mtcars" dataframe for example as you didn't provided the data:

Suppose for mtcars i like to count rows where cyl is equal to 4 and mpg is less than 25.

```
df = mtcars   
nrow(df[which(df$cyl == 4 & df$mpg< 25), ])
# [1] 5
```